# Trouble with push segue in iOS 6 on iPhone storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I have a CalculatorViewController with a button called Graph.  Clicking Graph causes a push segue to my CalculaterGraphViewController but instead it crashes when I push it.

My prepare to segue is set in CalculatorViewController.m as:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Show Graphs"])
    {
        // Do we need to set something else up in case it crashes 
    }   
}
```

After crashing I get this in my output:

2013-07-01 18:32:13.170 Calculator[1150:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'Show Graphs'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c95012 0x10d2e7e 0x46cf31 0x45eb99 0x45ec14 0x10e6705 0x1a2c0 0x1a258 0xdb021 0xdb57f 0xda6e8 0x49cef 0x49f02 0x27d4a 0x19698 0x1bf0df9 0x1bf0ad0 0x1c0abf5 0x1c0a962 0x1c3bbb6 0x1c3af44 0x1c3ae1b 0x1bef7e3 0x1bef668 0x16ffc 0x2abd 0x29e5 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

Comment: Post the crash log and we might be able to help.

Comment: i set the segue as a push with Show Graphs as the identifier

Comment: There are a bunch of potential problems (including delegate issues, misnamed segues, etc.).  So double-check your segue names, then let us know what the crash log reads, and how you're pushing, and (most likely issue) how your newVC initiates itself.

Comment: i'm new, whats the best way to set up a generic controller, the one being pushed to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need Navigation controller in order to use Push Segue!

A "push" style segue can only be done from a view controller that is being managed by a UINavigationController.

Comment: oh so how do i slide to another screen, i'm new

Comment: It's very simple, 1) select ViewController in the StoryBoard, then Editor->EmbedIn->NavigationController.

Comment: If you still can't figure out, please search "UINavigationController" tutorial on Youtube, that will for sure help you!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell it lays it out for you right in your crash log--You need to nest your CalculatorViewController within a UINavigationController.

Drag one out from the elements box in Interface Builder (or search for it by pressing Control-Cmd-Alt-3, and type UINavigationController). Set CalculatorViewController to be the UIViewController connected to the UINavigationController by control dragging from the UINavigationController and selecting the Relationship Segue as the root view controller.